# Make firefox to not ask to remember password

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

I have LastPass installed in Firefox which works fine, still Firefox asks me to remember password on many websites. How do I disable this feature? I want Firefox to not prompt for password because LastPass takes care of everything. See image below:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Firefox,

Click Tools -> Select Options -> Select Security and uncheck 'Remember passwords for sites' checkbox.

The following link may be useful:

http://developer.mozilla.org/En/How_to_Turn_Off_Form_Autocompletion